# I am trying to write an encryption program that takes a string and converts each variable to the ascii value, then saves file to text file

Tags: c++, string, encryption, ascii, offset

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int get_ascii_int(char ch);

int main()
{
    string test;
    char ch = 0;
    ofstream method1;
    int i = 0;
    int decision;
    int value;

    method1.open("method1.txt");

    cout << "Input a word or name: ";
    cin >> test;

    cout << test << endl;

    for (; i < test.size(); i++);
    {
        test[i];
        value = get_ascii_int(test[i]);
    }

    cout << "Would you like to display the file or save it, enter 1 for display or 2 for save? ";
    cin >> decision;

    if (decision == 1)
    {
        cout << "The encrypted code is " << value << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (method1.is_open())
        {
            method1 << "The encrpyted code is " << value << endl;
            method1.close();
        }
        else
            cout << "Unable to open file." << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
int get_ascii_int(char ch)
{
    return ((int)ch);
}
```

When I run the program it says the encryption is zero. How do I fix the for loop to run through each character and get the ascii value?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int get_offset_ascii(char ch, int offset);

int main()
{
    string test;
    int i = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    ofstream method2;
    int decision;
    int value = 1;

    method2.open("method2.txt");

    cout << "Input a word or name: ";
    getline(cin, test);
    test;

    for (; i < test.length(); i++);
    {
        char x = test.at(i);
        cout << int(x) << endl;
    }
    cout << "Would you like to display the file or save it, enter 1 for display or 2 for save? ";
    cin >> decision;

    if (decision == 1)
    {
        cout << "The encrypted code is " << value << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (method2.is_open())
        {
            method2 << "The encrypted code is " << value << endl;
            method2.close();
        }
        else
            cout << "Unable to open file." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int get_offset_ascii(char ch2, int offset)
{
    int new_offset_value;//the value after adding the determined offset to the ascii value of the letter
    new_offset_value = (int)ch2 + offset;
    (char)new_offset_value;

    return (new_offset_value);
}
```

This is a similar set up but it should print out the ascii value offset for each character in the string. I have them split because I was trying my best to fix it but couldn't. I just keep getting the answer of 0??

Please help I am really frustrated!

Comment: `for (; i < test.length(); i++);` <== remove semi-colon. And for all that is good in this world, *enable the highest warning levels your compiler can handle*. This should be warned by any half-decent compiler, Likewise `test;`, which does absolutely nothing, nor does `(char)new_offset_value;`

Answer (score 1):

Both of your programs share a very subtle bug:

```
for (; i < test.size(); i++);
```

See that semicolon at the end?

Let's reformat your code, so that you can see exactly what's going.

```
for (; i < test.size(); i++)
    ;

{
    test[i];
    value = get_ascii_int(test[i]);
}
```

What you thought was your for-loop, was really an empty loop. And the body of what you thought was a loop, was just an inner block, which was being executed with `i` set to the length of the string. Strictly, it's undefined behavior, but what it was likely doing is reading the null terminating byte of whatever text string you entered.

Comment: so how should i fix that?

Comment: I just explained to you how. Reread the answer. Unless the for() statement is immediately followed by a braced inner scope, the body of the for() loop is exactly one statement after the for(). The semicolon after the for() counts as a single, empty, statement, hence that's the body of your for() loop. Remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to answer the question but Sam Varsnavik was faster than me... :-)

The problem he pointed was the reason why you were receiving 0, as he said what you believed was the loop body was in fact ran only once as it was outside of the loop body.

Anyway, even with this fix your program won't achieve what you desire, which is "converting each character to a value" as you are storing only one value.

You should instead have a vector of values to store each value separately. Here is a sample code that will do the job :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int get_ascii_int(char ch);

int main()
{
    string test;
    char ch = 0;
    ofstream method1;
    int i = 0;
    int decision;
    vector<int> values;

    method1.open("method1.txt");

    cout << "Input a word or name: ";
    cin >> test;

    cout << test << endl;

    for (; i < test.size(); i++)
    {
        values.push_back(get_ascii_int(test[i]));
    }

    cout << "Would you like to display the file or save it, enter 1 for display or 2 for save? ";
    cin >> decision;

    if (decision == 1)
    {
        cout << "The encrypted code is ";
        for (i=0; i<values.size(); ++i)
            cout << values[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (method1.is_open())
        {
            method1 << "The encrpyted code is ";
            for (i=0; i<values.size(); ++i)
                cout << values[i] << " ";
            cout << endl;
            method1.close();
        }
        else
            cout << "Unable to open file." << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
int get_ascii_int(char ch)
{
    return ((int)ch);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    value = 0 ;


  for (; i < test.size(); i++)
        {
            test[i];
            value = (value*i) + get_ascii_int(test[i]);
        }
```